# Image Scrambling versus Image Encryption

Tags: image-processing

What is the difference between image scrambling and image encryption or are they the same thing in the context of image processing? What about in communication systems in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrambling is used for making a signal more white (I mean flat spectrum). Encryption is used for protecting the data from unauthorized listener. If you just scramble the data it is quite easy for a professional to descramble it and obtain the source image, but if you encrypt it then it is difficult or impossible to reverse it for someone without the code.

Comment: Then why would you want to scramble it?

Comment: I think one use case for scrambling could be captcha. You can "slightly" scramble a photo and ask the user what does it represent to be sure to be in presence of a human.